# `-fembed-bitcode` Error when trying to archive app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bitcode

I am trying to submit a new version of one of my client's apps to itunes connect, but I am getting this weird error

```
-fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0
```

This is the first time I am submitting a new version of this app using Xcode 7, I've always submitted new versions of the app fine in the past with Xcode 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcode is a new iOS feature that supports dynamic recompilation of uploaded binaries to support future devices and hardware configurations by Apple.

There is an option in **Xcode 7** under **Build Settings > Build Options** called **Enable Bitcode** where it can be enabled or disabled for your app.

Additionally, there is a setting in **iTunes Connect** for your apps under **Pricing and Availability > Bitcode-Auto-Recompilation** that you can set for your app.